# Not all UITextFields are calling all delegate methods

Tags: ios, delegates, uitextfield, xib, viewcontroller

I've got a view controller xib file with several views in it. I'm building a wizard-type interface. I'm just doing a simple fade between the views, and I'm already using a navigation controller for the main interface. I'd prefer not to use one for this wizard. Anyway, in the views, each panel has at least a button, some sort of input field (usually a `UITextField`) and some helper text hard coded in a `UILabel`.

The problem is that not all the `UITextField` objects are calling the `textFieldDidChange` method in the delegate (File's Owner - .m file associated with the xib), but all the `UITextField` objects ARE calling the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method.

Makes no sense to me. I feel like I must be missing something simple in how I set up the screens, but I'll be darned if I can figure it out. Each of the screens all look identical in the property sheets (on the right hand side of Xcode), and everything is wired up correctly in the File's Owner property sheet, both in `IBOutlet` and `IBActions`.

Here are some shots of what's going on...

Ideas? Thanks.

Here are links to the screen caps of the vital parts. 
(being a new member is making it hard to add all the info I need with screen caps!)

[image]
[image]

Comment: and another screen cap..


http://i.imgur.com/IEjLH.png

Comment: have you set each UITextField's delegate to your View Controller? (either in IB or programatically)

Comment: So, uhm... yeah, I'm an idiot. Let's just forget this ever happened. I was attaching my own notifiers, and I hadn't attached them on the last few UITextField objects. Sorry to bother... That'll teach me to look at this stuff with not enough caffeine onboard. :-) Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I now, there is no delegate method with the header `textFieldDidChange`. You have created a method of your own, which is depending on a NSNotification. Make sure all the `UITextField`s are send the right notification.

Comment: My confusion comes from the fact that it is firing for some of them...



UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification; object = <UITextField: 0x71b5b90; frame = (20 49; 278 30); text = '20'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = BM; tag = 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71b7320>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b5ce0>>}

Comment: So, uhm... yeah, I'm an idiot. Let's just forget this ever happened. I was attaching my own notifiers, and I hadn't attached them on the last few UITextField objects. Sorry to bother... That'll teach me to look at this stuff with not enough caffeine onboard. :-) Sorry.

Comment: You definitely pointed me toward it. My thoughts then went like "Wha...? ok, then why is this firing...?" And I started digging and then LMAO when I found the folded code with the observers. Like I said, not enough caffeine and folded code conspired against me. :-) Thanks again. 

As a side note, yeah, I started using the text field's shouldChangeCharactersInRange event, but I just didn't think it was a clean and simple as doing it with the observer. 

Thanks again, all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method on a `UITextFieldDelegate`

You may have confused `textViewDidChange`, which is a delegate method for a `UITextView`, but itis passed the `UITextView` that generated the event, not an `NSNotification`.

Seems like you want `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` instead.

Comment: Ok, weird. Why is it firing for some of them, then? I'll go back and look. Thanks.

Comment: I guess my confusion comes from the fact that it is firing on some of them...


UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification; object = <UITextField: 0x71b5b90; frame = (20 49; 278 30); text = '20'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = BM; tag = 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71b7320>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b5ce0>>}

Comment: So, uhm... yeah, I'm an idiot. Let's just forget this ever happened. I was attaching my own notifiers, and I hadn't attached them on the last few UITextField objects. Sorry to bother... That'll teach me to look at this stuff with not enough caffeine onboard. :-) Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. I'm a knucklehead. :-)

I was attaching my own notifier/observer and hadn't done so for the last few UITextField objects. Sorry to bother y'all.